# how can detect the pc's windows kind in local network

Tags: c#, networking, operating-system, local

I write a WinForms app,in local network how can understand that current pc's OS is server Windows or not?
thanks.

Comment: A related question and good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700605/getting-windows-os-version-programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are specific versions of windows:
[Operating system versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and have a look here:
[OperatingSystem.Platform Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.platform.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `System.OperatingSystem osInfo = System.Environment.OSVersion;`. To understand what the version numbers mean, you can take a look at [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304283).