# Getting Windows Build Number programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Using C#, how can I get the Windows build number or OS Build number as shown in the `About` window? This is different from the version number: for Windows 10 Creator Update, the Build Number would be `1703` and the OS Build would be `15063.296`.

I can't find anything relevant in `Environment.OSVersion` and this linked question [(Getting Windows OS version programmatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700605/getting-windows-os-version-programmatically) is only about getting the version number (`10` in this case)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700605/getting-windows-os-version-programmatically

Comment: Windows build number in your example - 15063. 1703 - this is *ReleaseId* 296 is *UBR* (*Update Build Revision*). look for *RtlGetVersion* and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` key

Comment: Why do you think you need this information? An app should not *ever* need to know the build number of the OS.

Comment: We encounter BSOD with this build of Windows.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question since this question is about the Windows 10 version (eg "1703") whereas the related question is about getting the major and minor version (eg "10.0").

Answer (score -3):

The following gets the Build number:

```
Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build
```

Comment: It gives me 9200 instead of 1703.

Comment: @Francois https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/sysinfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1